# Perform a task each interval

Tags: java, time, schedule

So I'm trying to schedule a time instance where it repeats every 10 seconds. Right now I have something that does a task after 10 seconds, but how do I make it so that it resets after doing so.

```
this.schedule = TimerManager.getInstance().schedule(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            chrs.get(0).getMap().spawnMonsterOnGroudBelow(MapleLifeFactory.getMonster(100100), chrs.get(0).getPosition());
        }

    }, time);

}
```

time is equal to 10000 milliseconds, and thus 10 seconds.

Comment: `"...but how do I make it so that it resets after doing so."` -- what do you mean by the term, *"reset"*?

Comment: Sorry, poor word choice. I just simply want the event to reoccur every given interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Create ScheduledExecutorService

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
```

2) Create and schedule your Runnable:

```
Runnable task = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Done:" + new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        // some long task can be here
        executor.schedule(this, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
};
//can be 0 if you want to run it fist time without 10 sec delay
executor.schedule(task, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

If you don't care about runnable duration and always want to fire event every 10 secs

```
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Done:" + new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    }
}, /* same, can be 0*/ 10 , 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

3) Use this when you exit program

```
executor.shutdown();
```

Comment: Will the executor turn off if I set the class instance that contains this code to null?

Comment: Nope. you have to shut it down first `executor.shutdown();` or `executor.shutdownNow();`

Comment: What's the difference between the two?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520189/difference-between-shutdown-and-shutdownnow-of-executor-service

Comment: Thanks a ton. You were really helpful and concise.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps consider using a ScheduledExecutorService

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use scheduleAtFixedRate method instead.

See this question [Creating a repeating timer reminder in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053383/creating-a-repeating-timer-reminder-in-java)